# WooCommerce Rest API Endpoint to get all the subscriptions tied to a particular customer

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I don’t know how to get a specific customer active subscriptions using the Woocommerce API. I have a mobile app which connects to a middle layer, this middle layer needs to provide the list of subscriptions the user has active. I need to know what Woocommerce API endpoint or combination of endpoints I can call to get the user's active subscriptions.
Been struggling for days to figure this out. Please help

e.g Using WooCommerce API v1 should return active subscriptions:
https://....com/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions?customer=1&status=active
but it doesn't, a lot of the users have missing active subscriptions.

I have also tried:
1.
https://….com/wp-json/wc/v3/memberships/members
Though this does return the memberships, it doesn’t provide product ids, etc, with them being null for many of the memberships

```
“id”: 355,
“customer_id”: 1,
“plan_id”: 430,
“status”: “active”,
“order_id”: null,
“product_id”: null,
“subscription_id”: null,
```

2.
https://….com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?customer=1
This is also missing subscriptions and other purchases

Comment: have you tried `/wc-api/v3/subscriptions` this?

Comment: @SajjadHossainSagor Yes I have, its in the description above. Thanks though :)

Comment: it seems you might need to create a custom REST API Endpoint & Endpoint Handler...  I once had to develop custom endpoints for an ios app bc some of wc api didn't work properly somehow... let me know some more details & i might help you with that

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * Register the routes for this class
 *
 * GET /customers/<id>/subscriptions
 *
 * @since 2.0
 * @param array $routes
 * @return array
 */
public function register_routes( $routes ) {
    # GET /customers/<id>/subscriptions
    $routes[ $this->base . '/(?P<id>\d+)/subscriptions' ] = array(
        array( array( $this, 'get_customer_subscriptions' ), WC_API_SERVER::READABLE ),
    );

    return $routes;
}
```

**Your Endpoint should be**  `/customers/<id>/subscriptions` - here `<id>` is `customer_id`

*WCS API function to get all the subscriptions tied to a particular customer.*

Comment: Thank you, to understand is this something thats already in the code, I can just call it, or did you give the above as an example of what I can add in? Do I just use the same base url as above?

Comment: @cfl - It's there in the WooCommerce subscriptions API itself.You may just use it

Comment: I get an 404 when calling that, "code": "rest_no_route",
  "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method". Im using the same base URL that works with the other calls

Comment: @cfl Which version of WC Subscription?

Comment: Tried v1 and v3

Comment: Check the Line# 55 /woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/api/legacy/class-wc-api-subscriptions-customers.php

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will try dig to figure that out. A question still remains through, how will the above be different to the https://....com/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions?customer=1&status=active

Comment: It didn't work cause it seems like the wordpress site itself might be setup weirdly, seems like the APIs I call as shown in the issue description is correct. The wordpress site seems to need fixing. Will report back once I figure out

Answer (score 0):

You can get active subscriptions using the following way:

```
/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions/<id> //To get particular subscription
/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions //To get all subscriptions
```

You can get more information here:
https://prospress.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-subscriptions

Let me know if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but thats what I have already tried, see the issue description. That call is missing subscriptions for some of the users, even though they show active on the actual website.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not looking for this anymore, but I figured I'd clarify *the answer since @mujuonly inconveniently* left out that it only applies to the `Legacy WooCommerce API`. Anyway, **it's deprecated.** but it works for now.

1. Enable the Legacy API in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> Legacy API
2. Get your access token
3. Visit `https://___.com/wc-api/v3/customers/<customer_id>/subscriptions/`

As of right now, I don't see anything like this endpoint supported in the native API. Hopefully it will be added in the near future.